# How to write the for condition and if condition combination?writing the code **For loop**

Tags: postgresql

I am writing the code **For loop**
my table have 2 columns main_bug_id,parent_id

```
main_bug_id   parent_id
1
2                1
3                2
```

have to check the main is in the parent bug or not, if the main bug is not in parent bug the task status have to update

```
for(record)
if (record.agent_assignment_id = parent_id)then

return parent_id in var_id
else if (record.agent_assignment_id = var_id)then
return variable_id 
else if
 update project.nt_task
 set status = 'Open'
 where key_val_id = variable_id 

end if;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need a for loop for that. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the table definition of the `nt_task` table.

Comment: But the agent_assignment_id and parent_id are from different table nt_task is another table

Comment: You should edit your question. First of all you cannot use ```for``` keyword in select statement. Do you need to write postgre function?